# Htaccess resposable links

Tags: .htaccess

I have link like this for example http://localhost/somepage.php?id=1. And i want to make link like this http://localhost/somepage/1 but not just on somepage.php but for all pages on localhost. Here is my code for hidding .php extension and now i now i got http://localhost/somepage?id=1 and now i need to get http://localhost/somepage/1.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Have you tried any rule?

Comment: yes, for now i can make link like this http://localhost/somepage?id=1 and i tryed more rules but not working

Comment: If you show your attempt in question even if it doesn't work then we can help you out.

Comment: question is updated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your rule with this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/?$ $1.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: yes but if is some way to dynamic do not just for id but for all ?something=value if you understand

Comment: Well a rule cannot guess query parameter. Only option you have is to include query parameter in pretty URI itself like `http://localhost/somepage/id/1`